# No Such Client Exception Spring Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement Spring Security OAuth2 using Java config.

My usecase requires the use of password grant_type.

I have configured this so far without the need for a web.xml and would prefer to keep it that way

Versions I am using:

- Spring Framework: 4.1.6
- Spring Security: 4.0.1
- Spring Security OAuth:2.0.7

To make explaining this easier I have enabled GET on the token endpoint

```
    @Override
    public void configure
        (AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception
    {
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET); //<-- Enable GET
    }
```

The request that I am making is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/oauth/token?
    client_id=testClient&
    grant_type=password&
    username=user&
    password=password
```

The header includes an Authorization header that contains the encoded version of:

```
Username: user
Password: password
```

The exception I get is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.NoSuchClientException:
   No client with requested id: user
```

From the exception description it appears that OAuth is looking in the ClientDetailsService for the client: *user*. However *user* is a user credential. I am obviously missunderstanding something about the configuration.

My configuration is as follows;

**ServletInitializer.java**

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(getClass()));
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException{
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        DelegatingFilterProxy filter = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");
    filter.setContextAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher");
        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.
            inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/Services/*")
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

**OAuth2ServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired 
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{

            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("testClient")
                    .secret("secret")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception{
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET);
        }

        @Override 
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources){
            resources.resourceId("SomeResourseId").stateless(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

            http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
        }
    }
}
```

Code in gitrepo for ease of access: https://github.com/dooffas/springOauth2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where the 500 comes from in your case. I see a 406 because there is no JSON converter for the access token (Spring used to register one by default for Jackson 1.* but now it only does it for Jackson 2.*). You token endpoint works for me if I add jackson-databind to the classpath, e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This works for me:

```
$ curl -v testClient:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token?'grant_type=password&username=user&password=password'
```

P.S. you really ought not to use GET for a token request.

Comment: I did see the 406 as well, your suggestion of adding the dependancy has solved that. However, I still get NoSuchClientException. 
It appears to try and use 'user' as the client id, but this is a username? The GET is only for testing

Comment: Then you must be sending the wrong data (I'll add a curl command to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined different authorities

try this:

```
@Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.
            inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER", "CLIENT");
    }
```

And add param `grant_type=password` to your request

Comment: Unfortunatly this results in the same exception.

Comment: @dooffas have look at your config: `.authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")` chane it to `CLIENT`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the Roles defined for a user need to match (or have a matching) authority in the client. However this causes the same error.

Comment: @doofas do you have \@EnableResourceServer

Comment: Currently, no. I didn't think one was required to be granted an access token. My assumption is based on the fact that you can have the Authorization server and Resource server in two separate applications. For completeness, I have updated the code and have now included a Resource server.